# Auth0 Node.js/Express Backend - Get user.sub?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, backend, auth0

Building a simple ToDo app using React frontend, Node.js/Express backend, and MySQL DB using Auth0 for authentication. I have a userId column in my tasks DB holding the user.sub ID value, specifying who owns the task. I want users to see only their own tasks, which I presume can be done by comparing to user.sub in the JWT to the column.

My question: How do I refer to the user.sub value in my code? I was able to figure it out pretty easily in React but having trouble figuring this out in the backend.

Server.js (code snippets below are truncated):

```
const express = require("express");
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); /* deprecated */
const cors = require("cors");
const path = __dirname + '/app/views/';
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path));

var corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); /* bodyParser.urlencoded() is deprecated */

require("./app/routes/task.routes.js")(app);

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

task.routes.js:

```
module.exports = app => {
    const tasks = require("../controllers/task.controller.js");
    const { auth } = require('express-oauth2-jwt-bearer');

    const checkJwt = auth({
        audience: 'https://my-auth0-app.com',
        issuerBaseURL: `https://dev-X-XXXXX.us.auth0.com/`,
    });

    var router = require("express").Router();

    // Retrieve all Tasks
    router.get("/", checkJwt, tasks.findAll);

    app.use('/api/tasks', router);
};
```

task.controller.js - showing my route which fetches all tasks:

```
const Task = require("../models/task.model.js");

...

// Retrieve all Tasks from the database (with condition).
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.query.userId;

    Task.getAll(userId, (err, data) => {
        if (err)
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving tasks."
            });
        else res.send(data);
    });
};
```

...and finally, task.model.js - this is where I think I need to leverage code to read the user.sub value from the jwt:

```
const sql = require("./db.js");

// constructor
const Task = function(task) {
    this.userId = task.userId;
    this.title = task.title;
    this.description = task.description;
    this.completed = task.completed;
    this.startDate = task.startDate;
};

...

Task.getAll = (userId, result) => {
    let query = `SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE userId LIKE '<<USER.SUB VALUE>>'`;

    sql.query(query, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            result(null, err);
            return;
        }

        console.log("tasks: ", res);
        result(null, res);
    });
};

module.exports = Task;
```

If I hardcode a userId value into the above SQL query, it works and the only tasks that show are those matching the userId value. So my next step is figuring out how to dynamically grab the logged-in user's userId from the JWT and insert it into the SQL statement. I've done a lot of experimenting and Google-fu but no dice so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the userId and the other user data in the backend as follows:

```
router.get('/', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const token = req.auth; 
  const userData = await auth0.getProfile(token);
  res.send("Got user data");
});
```

The userData object should have the following data fields:

```
{
  sub: 'google-oauth2|56789456789',
  given_name: 'Joe',
  family_name: 'Doe',
  nickname: 'joe',
  name: 'Joe Doe',
  picture: 'http://someimageurl.com',
  locale: 'en-US',
  updated_at: '2023-03-20T20:19:24.791Z',
  email: 'joe@doe.com',
  email_verified: true
}
```